# Does Integral form of L'Hospital Rule exist.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

According to L'Hospital Rule if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is either $\frac{0}0$ or $\frac{∞}∞$ and if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be differentiable then $\lim_{x\to a}$${f(x)}\over{g(x)}$ $=$ $\lim_{x\to a}$${f'(x)}\over {g'(x)}$ only if $\lim_{x\to a}$${f'(x)}\over {g'(x)}$ exists.

Now would it be correct to say that, if for some functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ $\lim_{x\to a}$${f(x)}\over {g(x)}$ exists and is equal to k

then $lim_{x\to a}$${\int f(x)}\over {\int g(x)}$ = k (if it exists) or = $\frac{0}0$

For an example question:

Let $f(x)$ & $g(x)$ be two differentiable functions and $\lim_{x\to 2}$${f'(x)}\over {g'(x)}$ exists.$g(x) = 2x^2 - 8$ and $f'(x) = 4x^3$. Find $f(x)$

Sol : as $\lim_{x\to 2}$${f'(x)}\over {g'(x)}$ exists and is equal to 4 $lim_{x\to 2}$${\int f'(x)}\over {\int g'(x)}$ = 4 (if it exists) or = $\frac{0}0$

Which implies that $lim_{x\to 2}$${f(x)}\over {g(x)}$ = $\frac{0}0$ as $lim_{x\to 2}$$g(x) = 0$

=> $lim_{x\to 2}$$f(x) = 0$ also  $f(x) = x^4 + c$

=> $f(2) = 2^4 + c = 0$ => c = -16

Therefore  $f(x) = x^4 -16$

Things that contradict the rule:

if $\lim_{x\to a}$${f(x)}\over {g(x)}$ exists and is equal to k

then $lim_{x\to a}$${\int f(x)}\over {\int g(x)}$ will never be equal to k as if this limit exists and is not in an indeterminant form then $lim_{x\to a}$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ may or may not exist and therefore it should not be equal to k

Comment: In the theorem, the condition of $\int f/\int g$ being an indeterminate form, is part of the hypothesis, not part of what the theorem gives.

Comment: The antiderivative is not unique,  so in some cases $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{\int f(x)}{\int g(x)}$ could be any real number, depending on the integration constants you choose. It's not a well defined expression.

Comment: But $lim_{x\to a}$${\int f(x)}\over {\int g(x)}$ should to be equal to k if it is not in a indeterminate form

Comment: You're using MathJax incorrectly, instead of writing separate math expression like `$lim_{x\to 2}$$f(x) = 0$` write `$lim_{x\to 2} f(x) = 0$`. And avoid using unusual characters like ∞ (use `\infty` to get $\infty$). [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a guide to improve your MathJax writing.

Comment: As I said, that's not well defined. Take for example $f(x) =2x+2$ and $g(x) =2x+1$. Then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =2$ but $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\int f(x)}{\int g(x)}$ is not well defined because you can take, for example, the antiderivatives $\int f(x) = x^2+2x+17$ and $\int g(x) = x^2+x+\pi$ and get $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\int f(x)}{\int g(x)}=\frac{17}{\pi}$

Comment: Well if $f(x) / g(x) \to L$ as $x\to a$ and the functions are continuous then we have $\int_a^x f(t) \, dt/\int_a^x g(t) \, dt \to L$ as $x\to a$.

Comment: How would you prove that ?

Comment: The holistic explanation is because $f$ is continuous, when $x$ is close to $a, f(t)$ is close to $f(x)$, so $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt \approx f(x)|x-a|$. And the same is true of $g$, so $\int_a^x f(t) \, dt/\int_a^x g(t) \, dt \approx f(x)/g(x)$, with the approximation improving as $x\to a$.  Cleaning that up into an actual proof is straight-forward.